Number of trees contained in a square
I am trying to find if there are any answers, partial or complete, to the following question:
Given the square lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ equipped with the norm $||x|| = \{\max(x_1,x_2)\}$ for a point $x = (x_1,x_2)$, how many distinct lattice trees can be made containing the origin as a vertex and contained in the square $B_r = \{x \in Z^2 : ||x|| ≤ r \} ? $
I am not making any requirements on the numbers of vertices or edges of the trees, and not requiring they all fit together at once. I've managed to find some bounds in a specific case I'm interested in, but I'm wondering if there any results for general trees (or suggestions on going about finding them).

Which norm is $| ...|$ $\ell^1, \ell^{\infty}...$ ?

You might look into Kirchoff's matrix-tree theorem lets you find the number of spanning trees of any graph by computing a determinant. This doesn't fully answer your question though since you're not restricting to spanning trees.
